# Call a function that receives an array using a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So I've this:

```
int main()
{
    int workers;
    printf("How many workers are there?\n");
    scanf("%d", &workers);
    printf("What are their preferences?\n");
    int *pref = malloc(workers * sizeof(int));
    if (pref == NULL)
        return -1;

    fillPreferences(pref, workers);

  return 0;
}
```

I want now to fill the "pref" 2d array in this function:

```
void fillPreferences(int pref[][], int size)
{
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            scanf(" %d", &pref[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work, probably because I'm using the pointer wrong. How can I use malloc and then call a function and receive the values in the 2d array by doing pref[i][j]? (Note that I'm not looking to do something like scanf(..., &pref+i) or whatever. I need to actually use that 2d array.

Thanks :)

Comment: There is no 2D array. And also no array of pointers or similar. And the function does not take a "pointer to array".

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And how can I fix it?

Comment: `void fillPreferences(int pref[], int size){  for (int i=0;i<size;i++) scanf(" %d", &pref[i]); }`

Comment: I need to receive inputs to a 2D array...

Comment: First, You create a 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `a[i]`, it is turned into `*(a+i)`. That is, `a[i]` accesses the memory by `a+i` address (well, it is `a+i*sizeof(element)` even).

As such, `a[i][j]` means `*(*(a+i)+j)`. **Two** memory accesses. For this to work, your `a` should be an array of arrays. That is, you need to `malloc` its elements first and then `malloc` a memory to hold them.

In your particular case, i doubt you need it. What you need is make it 1D-array (which is it already) and calculate index from your two indices in whatever fashion you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Your pref array is 1D so you can make it in this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void fillPreferences(int **pref, int size)
{
    int prefNum=0;
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {   
            puts("Number of preferences");
            scanf("%d",&prefNum);               
            pref[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*prefNum);
            puts("Enter preferences");
            for(int j=0;j<prefNum;j++){
                scanf(" %d", &pref[i][j]);    
            }   

    }
}

int main()
{
    int workers;
    printf("How many workers are there?\n");
    scanf("%d", &workers);
    printf("What are their preferences?\n");
    int **pref = malloc(workers * sizeof(int *));       
    if (pref == NULL)
        return -1;




    fillPreferences(pref, workers);
    // Show values
    printf("%d %d %d",pref[0][0],pref[1][0],pref[2][0]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I need to receive inputs like:
{1 2 3}
{2 4 3}
{5 2 4} - 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

You allocate memory for a 1D array, but the function you have is designed to accept a 2D array and fill it (although the function definition is incorrect and won't compile).

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fillPreferences(int** pref, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &pref[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int workers;
    printf("How many workers are there?\n");
    scanf("%d", &workers);

    printf("What are their preferences?\n");
    int **pref = malloc(workers * sizeof(int*));
    if (pref == NULL)
        return -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < workers; i++)
    {
        pref[i] = malloc(workers * sizeof(int));
        if(pref[i] == NULL)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                free(pref[j]);
            free(pref);
            return -1;
    }

    fillPreferences(pref, workers);

    /* Don't forget to `free` everything after its use! */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Is there any way I can actually do what you do there only with void fillPreferences(int[] pref, int size)? Because I'm kinda asked to use that declaration..